# How to set up continuous integration for Unity on Linux

Tags: unity-game-engine, continuous-integration, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to create a system for building a Unity project each time it is changed with git. I would like to use [Semaphore](https://semaphoreci.com/lahsunity/multiplayer-fps-networking-ci-experiment/settings/scheduled_build_settings/new) or [Shippable](https://www.shippable.com/) because of the free plan options. However, I don't know how to set up a system to automatically build a Unity project on Linux. Online, I can find documentation on how to do it for Mac with TravisCI, but this is not an option for me. How could I install Unity onto Ubuntu from the command line and then use the CLI build a project from a git repo? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can. If that answers your question

Comment: I meant “how could I”... I’ve updated the question.

Comment: You could use a virtual machine (Ubuntu - if you prefer). You would first need to install Unity from here https://beta.unity3d.com/download/170f0691b973/public_download.html
Then you could install git and pull your repo (or create one). As I understand you want Unity to listen to the repo for changes. You can leave it running with an editor script that is doing just that. Upon change in the repo, you could make unity execute a `BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(playerOptions);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Github](https://github.com) or [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com) pipelines. Every change, submit your code using git and they will build your game automatically.

Use https://game.ci/ workflow. They have a quite complete set of scripts and configurations.